# i am having problem while importing libraries in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
import segmentation_models as sm
%load_ext tensorboard
import datetime
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model


error:


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-fb82ca23d179> in <module>
     20 import cv2
     21 import tensorflow as tf
---> 22 import segmentation_models as sm
     23 model = tf.keras.applications.segmentation_model(model_name='mask_rcnn', weights='imagenet')
     24 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'tensorboard')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/efficientnet/__init__.py in init_keras_custom_objects()
     69     }
     70 
---> 71     tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils.get_custom_objects().update(custom_objects)
     72 
     73 

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'get_custom_objects'
```

libraries should be imported successfully.
my tensorflow version is 2.11.0
and i am using google colab

Answer (score 2):

Either downgrade `tensorflow` to version `1.x` or upgrade `segmentation_models` so that it can work with `tensorflow_2.x`. If you can't do both of these then use the `compat` behavior of TensorFlow as follows.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 0):

!pip install tensorflow==2.10.0

!pip install keras==2.10.0

!pip install segmentation-models

import segmentation_models as sm

Hi..
Current version is 2.11.0 so downgrade to 2.10.0 .Above code fixed the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).